# MVC 5 security concern related to viewmodel XSS, SQL Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, xss, sql-injection

Can somebody please explain what exactly `ModelState.IsValid` means in a MVC action controller?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Something(MyViewModel model)
    {            
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
    }
```

I know that ValidateAntiForgeryToken does some protection related to the form posting origin.

If a malicious user will bypass the form validation on the client side and manage to post some malicious code to my action method, will it be detected by `ModelState.IsValid`?

How can I best protect on the server side, once a form has been posted to my app?

Do I have to manually check the model that it doesn't contain XSS or SQL malicious code?

P.S.

I use EF Code First and I think is quite safe but want to be sure.

Comment: if need more help then plz comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelState.IsValid` means that all the validations etc which you have used in your model class is valid or not..

for ex:-

```
 public class Emp
 {
    [Required]
    public int EmpCd { get; set; }
 }
```

**So if during post EmpCd has null or string value it will make ModelState as Invalid..**

**This is basically used if you manage to avoid the UI unobtrusive client validation ,then `ModelState.IsValid` will validate.**

**ModelState.IsValid tells you if any model errors have been added to
 ModelState.**

The default model binder will add some errors for basic type
 conversion issues (for example, passing a "string" for something
 which is an "int").

**The sample DataAnnotations model binder will fill model state with
 validation errors taken from the DataAnnotations attributes on your
 model.**

Comment: So basically if you manage to avoid the UI client validation, once the form is submitted then is validated one more time to be sure ... something like `unobtrusive validation` for server side ?